# How do I generate different random numbers in a loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, random

I'm trying to make a dice game that uses 6 dice. I can generate a random number each roll, the problem is that I keep getting that same number (if the generated number is 1, each dice is 1). Is there a way to make it so that each dice doesn't get the same number?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    int i;
    int diceRoll;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = (rand()%6)+1;

    printf("\t\t\t Welcome to Dice Game!\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 6; i ++){
        diceRoll= r;
        printf(" %d \n", diceRoll);
    }

 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put this in the `for` loop:

```
r = (rand()%6)+1;
```

And declare `r` outside of it like this:

```
int r;
```

`OR` you don't use r and the program would look something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    int count, diceRoll;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\t\t\t Welcome to Dice Game!\n");

    for(count = 0; count < 6; count ++){
        diceRoll = (rand()%6)+1;
        printf(" %d \n", diceRoll);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I guess I defined r a little too early. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider

```
for( i = 0; i < 6; i ++){
    diceRoll= (rand()%6) + 1;
    printf(" %d \n", diceRoll);
}
```